# If $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ in which every polynomial of degree $\geq3$ is reducible, then $\bar{K}/K$ has degree $1$ or $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is it true that if $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ in which every polynomial of degree 3 is reducible, then $\bar{K}/K$ has degree 1 or 2? I have thought of taking $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$. Then $K\subset K(\alpha)\subset\bar{K}$. From the condition on the degree of irreducible polynomials $[K(\alpha):K]=1,2$ and $[\bar{K}:K]=[\bar{K}:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$. Can I guess something about $[\bar{K}:K(\alpha)]$?
The whole situation looks just like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: Put the relevant context into your post, instead of waiting until people spend time answering your question only for you to object because you don't know the background material yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Primitive Element Theorem says that every finite separable extension is simple; that is, if $L/K$ is a field extension that is finite, and $L$ is separable over $K$, then there exists $\alpha\in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$. Extensions of fields of characteristic $0$ are necessarily separable, so finite extensions of fields of characteristic zero are always simple.

If $\alpha\in \overline{K}$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, so its characteristic polynomial has degree either $1$ or $2$. If you always get degree $1$, then $\alpha\in K$ for all $\alpha\in\overline{K}$, so you have $\overline{K}=K$.

If there is at least one $\alpha$ with $[K(\alpha):K]$  of degree $2$, let $\beta\in \overline{K}$.  Then we have a tower $K\subseteq K(\alpha)\subseteq K(\alpha,\beta)$.
Since $K(\alpha,\beta)=K(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$ by the Primitive Element Theorem, we have $[K(\beta,\alpha):K] = [K(\gamma):K]\leq 2$. Therefore,
$$2\geq [K(\gamma):K] = [K(\gamma):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K] =2[K(\gamma):K(\alpha)]\geq 2$$
so $[K(\gamma):K(\alpha)]= 1$. This proves that $\gamma\in K(\alpha)$. Thus, $\overline{K}\subseteq K(\alpha)$, hence they are equal. Thus $[\overline{K}:K] = [K(\alpha):K] = 2$.

In summary, if $K$ has characteristic $0$ and irreducible polynomials over $K$ always have degree $1$ or $2$, then either $[\overline{K}:K]=1$ or $[\overline{K}:K]=2$.